# VBA Function to loop through all of the worksheeets in active workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code below which runs perfectly in the active worksheet,

```
Sub NYTimes()
'
' MMto000 Macro

    Dim MyRange As Range, MyCell As Range

        Set MyRange = Range("K13:M2000,U13:W2000,AI13:AJ2000")
        For Each MyCell In MyRange
            If MyCell.Value > 0 Then
                MyCell.Value = MyCell.Value * 1000
            End If
        Next MyCell

End Sub
```

I want to run this code through all the worksheets in the active workbook. So I wrote the below code but it doesn't work. Any help on this mill be much appreciated.

```
Sub NYTimes()
'
' MMto000 Macro

    Dim MyRange As Range, MyCell As Range
    Dim Current As Worksheet
    For Each Current In Worksheets

        Set MyRange = Range("K13:M2000,U13:W2000,AI13:AJ2000")
        For Each MyCell In MyRange
            If MyCell.Value > 0 Then
                MyCell.Value = MyCell.Value * 1000
            End If
        Next MyCell
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to attach the worksheet to each Range Object: `Current.Range("K13...`

Comment: Hi Scott, Thats Great!!! It sorted the issue. Thanks for your valuable help!!!

Comment: Scott, you should post this as an Answer and not a comment.

Comment: @Graham this has been answered so many times, it was quicker to comment than find the duplicate.

Comment: If people would just search before hand, they could save themselves tons of time.

Comment: I appreciate your comment about people saving time. But I am quite new to programming and this environment so it does take a while to get used to things. Its like a driver who is learning will make few silly mistakes which other drivers might find annoying but that's not done on purpose. All in good faith.